# numpy prints list() around each list

Tags: python, list, numpy, printing

I have an array of list containing lemmatized words. When I print many of them at once, this is the output:

```
print(data[:3])

[list(['@', 'switchfoot', 'http', ':', '//twitpic.com/2y1zl', '-', 'Awww', ',', 'that', "'s", 'a', 'bummer', '.', 'You', 'shoulda', 'got', 'David', 'Carr', 'of', 'Third', 'Day', 'to', 'do', 'it', '.', ';', 'D'])
 list(['is', 'upset', 'that', 'he', 'ca', "n't", 'update', 'his', 'Facebook', 'by', 'texting', 'it', '...', 'and', 'might', 'cry', 'a', 'a', 'result', 'School', 'today', 'also', '.', 'Blah', '!'])
 list(['@', 'Kenichan', 'I', 'dived', 'many', 'time', 'for', 'the', 'ball', '.', 'Managed', 'to', 'save', '50', '%', 'The', 'rest', 'go', 'out', 'of', 'bound'])]
```

I tried many thing to get rid of it but it never does, but when I tried:

```
a = [[i for i in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
print(np.array(a))
```

the output is not with list() around every list:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

does it mean they are different lists? Does it just happen with list of string? How can I get rid of it, if it is necessary of course, thanks for your time.

Comment: Inner numpy arrays should have equal number of elements. In your example the first list has 27, the second 25 and the last 21 elements. Therefore numpy stores them as python objects.

Comment: An array of list objects will always print the `list` part. When you do `np.array(a)` it will create a 2 dimensional array of either 32 or 64 bit integers depending on your system.

Comment: Is there any capability for numpy to work with jagged arrays?

Comment: @kevinkayaks only with the `object` dype array or `np.array` objects, but why would you want to? That would remove the advantage. Might as well use a list or lists

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily remove the advantage for certain operations. Like two 2D arrays where the second axis has variable length: one could imagine broadcasting would be lost, but aligned operations could be done without a for loop

Answer (score 0):

you could potentialy loop through the 3 lists and print them with the * sympol in front.

```
for i in data[:3]:
  print(*i)
```

this would in normal cases remove the brackets and commas of the list and just print it with spaces. I must admit though that i do not under stand how you got your output, so this is just my 2 cents. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
print(data[:3].tolist())
```

Convert the array to a list.  This will use the list of list display, as opposed to an array of lists.

But as hashed out in the comments, there is a significant difference between an array of lists, and a 2d array.

---

Including `list` is the display is a relatively recent change in `numpy`.  It was added, I think, to clarify the underlying nature of the elements of an object dtype array.

Consider, for example, an array with a variety of element types:

```
In [532]: x=np.empty(5,object)
In [533]: x[0]=[1,2,3]; x[1]=(1,2,3); x[2]=np.array([1,2,3]); x[3]=np.matrix([1,2,3]); x[4]={0:1}
In [534]: x
Out[534]: 
array([list([1, 2, 3]), 
       (1, 2, 3), 
       array([1, 2, 3]), 
       matrix([[1, 2, 3]]),
       {0: 1}], 
       dtype=object)
```

I tweaked the layout for clarity.  But note that without the words, the list and array elements would look a lot alike.

Converting the array to a list, we get the default formatting of a list:

```
In [537]: x.tolist()
Out[537]: [[1, 2, 3], (1, 2, 3), array([1, 2, 3]), matrix([[1, 2, 3]]), {0: 1}]
```

The elements of the array and list are same.